# How to show the trigger(s) associated with a view or a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, postgresql-triggers

I have one requirement that I have to get the list of triggers associated to the given table/view.
Can anyone help me to find the triggers for a table in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Pgadmin shows you a lot of information about a table when you look at it. Does it show triggers as well? I know it's not really an answer to the question, just curious.

Comment: @Bill- pgadmin tool is not present in the box.

Comment: \df will list all the functions including triggers.

Answer (score 101):

This will return all the details you want to know

```
select * from information_schema.triggers;
```

or if you want to sort the results of a specific table then you can try

```
SELECT event_object_table
      ,trigger_name
      ,event_manipulation
      ,action_statement
      ,action_timing
FROM  information_schema.triggers
WHERE event_object_table = 'tableName' -- Your table name comes here
ORDER BY event_object_table
     ,event_manipulation;
```

---

the following will return table name that has trigger

```
select relname as table_with_trigger
from pg_class
where pg_class.oid in (
        select tgrelid
        from pg_trigger
        );
```

Comment: Thanks for the details. information_schema.triggers will have entry for views as well?

Comment: @dude- Can we get it for views. Is there any way to get it for view?

Comment: dude - it is not showing any views for select * from information_schema.triggers ;.  Since views are not physical entity it is not showing it in the information_schema.triggers table. What are the triggers pertaining to tables that are used to create view is applicable. Is my understanding correct Please correct me

Comment: how can i drop the triggers which i get from this query • select event_object_schema as table_schema,event_object_table as table_name,trigger_schema,trigger_name,string_agg(event_manipulation, ',') as event,action_timing as activation,
action_condition as condition,action_statement as definition from information_schema.triggers where event_object_table like 'his_%' and trigger_name ='set_timestamp' group by 1,2,3,4,6,7,8
order by table_schema,table_name;

Answer (score 43):

The problem with the view [`information_schema.triggers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-triggers.html) (besides being slow) is, [per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-triggers.html):

> The view triggers contains all triggers defined in the current
> database on tables and views that the current user owns or has some
> privilege other than `SELECT` on.

Meaning, you only get to see triggers you have appropriate privileges on.

To see *all* triggers for a table, look in the system catalog [`pg_trigger`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html)

```sql
SELECT tgname
     , tgisinternal, pg_get_triggerdef(oid) AS definition  -- optional additions
FROM   pg_trigger
WHERE  tgrelid = 'myschema.mytbl'::regclass;  -- optionally schema-qualified
```

I added `tgisinternal` to show which are *internal* triggers, and `pg_get_triggerdef(oid)` to get the definition (mostly relevant for non-internal triggers).

Works for tables *and* views.
Or you could use a GUI like pgAdmin that displays the list under the table node in the object browser.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this is as useful as the view `information_schema.triggers` (assuming appropriate priviledges).  With the view, I get the `trigger_name`, `event_manipulation` (ie, I, U, D), `action_timing` (eg, BEFORE), the `event_object_table` the trigger acts on, and the `action_statement`.  With `SELECT tgname...` all I get is the trigger name, which seems to be lacking a lot of context, and the other fields in `pg_trigger` don't seem all that informative.  I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: @Randall: This question asks for a *list of triggers*. Maybe you want to ask your own question with your requirements?

Comment: @Randall It's an internal system table so it requires some additional interpretation to be human friendly.

Answer (score 10):

On psql command-line tool you can also use `\dS <table_name>` (from https://serverfault.com/questions/331024/how-can-i-show-the-content-of-a-trigger-with-psql)

Comment: This doesn't include 'system generated triggers', e.g. for foreign-key constraints, in case you (the reader of this comment) want to see those. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25204845/173497) for a solution that does include those.

Answer (score 2):

```
select    tgname
    ,relname
    ,tgenabled
    ,nspname    from    pg_trigger 
    join    pg_class    on    (pg_class.oid=pg_trigger.tgrelid) 
    join    pg_namespace    on    (nspowner=relowner);


tgenabled (To check if its disabled)

O = trigger fires in "origin" and "local" modes, 
D = trigger is disabled, 
R = trigger fires in "replica" mode,
A = trigger fires always.
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

\df will list all the functions including triggers.

\dft will list all the triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that infoschema does NOT contain key relation table information about triggers (at least in postgres 10).  pg_triggers does contain this info.  Also noticed that datagrip will not script relation tables when you script the triggers, so i'm assuming that it uses infoschema to script them (and then your table would be missing the relation tables, and the trigger functions referencing them would fail). PG documentation says that columns in infoschema for action_reference_old_table applies to a feature not available in postgres(10), but i'm definitely using them, and they definitely show up in pg_triggers.  FYI.

Answer (score 0):

You can show all user-defined triggers in the current database with [information_schema.triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/infoschema-triggers.html) and [pg_trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html) as shown below. *There is no way to show all triggers in all databases at once:

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.triggers;
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_trigger;
```