# Deleted trigger in Postgres - still trying to run somewhere. Showing up as failed in postgres Log

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, pgadmin

I'm not even sure where to begin in exploring this one.

I have a postgres database. I created three functions that look like this one -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mid1_spm()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    insert into machines_spm_storage ( SELECT * FROM machineid1_spm_step4);
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION mid1_spm()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I used the following script to create the trigger:

```
--trigger function to populate spm storage table
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mid3_spm() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    insert into machines_spm_storage ( SELECT * FROM machineid3_spm_step4);
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;


--trigger to initiate function
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_mid3_spm
    AFTER UPDATE ON machines_machineevent
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mid3_spm();
```

**The goal of the trigger is to pull data from a view and store it in the machines_spm_storage table.**

When I first created the test trigger the table name was machine_5_spm_storage. Now I keep getting this error (in postgres logs)

```
2017-03-06 14:05:01 EST [9468-1] epic@epic_ar_db ERROR:  relation "machine_5_spm_storage" does not exist at character 13
2017-03-06 14:05:01 EST [9468-2] epic@epic_ar_db STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO machine_5_spm_storage ( SELECT * FROM machine_5_spm_step4);
```

I have deleted this table, deleted all triggers, restarted the postgres service, dropped and rebuilt the database. I have no idea why (or even HOW) it's still trying to run my original trigger.

I had just deleted the original to fine-tune what I had. I did discover if I change the table name I'm trying to insert the data into to the one in the error - the problem goes away and the trigger works fine. But there's nothing in the script that even references that old table.

ANY help or ideas are appreciated!

P.S. I know the trigger works in and of itself - my problem is that it seems to keep referencing a table that no longer exists. And it's not recognizing that I have created a new one - same function - I just changed the name).

UPDATE: Here is what the newest version of the trigger and function looks like:

Function:

```
-- Function: mid1_spm()

-- DROP FUNCTION mid1_spm();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mid1_spm()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    insert into machines_spm_storage ( SELECT * FROM machineid1_spm_step4);
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION mid1_spm()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_mid2_spm
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON machines_machineevent
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE mid2_spm();
```

The only difference really is the name of the view and the name of the table. But I completely dropped (cascaded) the original test version.

Today the postgres log looks like this:

```
2017-03-07 10:45:01 EST [12069-1] epic@epic_ar_db ERROR:  relation "machine_5_spm_storage" does not exist at character 13
2017-03-07 10:45:01 EST [12069-2] epic@epic_ar_db STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO machine_5_spm_storage ( SELECT * FROM machine_5_spm_step4);
2017-03-07 10:50:01 EST [12210-1] epic@epic_ar_db ERROR:  relation "machine_5_spm_storage" does not exist at character 13
2017-03-07 10:50:01 EST [12210-2] epic@epic_ar_db STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO machine_5_spm_storage ( SELECT * FROM machine_5_spm_step4);
2017-03-07 10:55:02 EST [12434-1] epic@epic_ar_db ERROR:  relation "machine_5_spm_storage" does not exist at character 13
2017-03-07 10:55:02 EST [12434-2] epic@epic_ar_db STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO machine_5_spm_storage ( SELECT * FROM machine_5_spm_step4);
2017-03-07 11:00:01 EST [12759-1] epic@epic_ar_db ERROR:  relation "machine_5_spm_storage" does not exist at character 13
2017-03-07 11:00:01 EST [12759-2] epic@epic_ar_db STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO machine_5_spm_storage ( SELECT * FROM machine_5_spm_step4);
```

It's trying to run the triggers, but failing because (somehow) it's referencing the ORIGINAL name of the view and table - even though it's not written that way. I'm at a complete loss for this one.

UPDATE as of 3/7/17 - I deleted all of the triggers I created. And that script is STILL trying to run somehow. So I guess this is a different problem than first realized. The script is still failing and showing up in the log even though there are NO triggers, No functions and no running jobs.

Comment: if you are using pgadmin maybe you need refresh the tree. Also check this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25204845/3470178

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Hey! :) I did refresh the tree, even the individual triggers and the tables. I also restarted the postgres service. I'm not even sure how it's running it for a table that doesn't exist.  I just checked on the logs again this morning and it's still trying to run the triggers but it's trying to run it with that original table name (and it doesn't even exist). It's not written that way ANYWHERE that i can find.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - noticed something interesting I deleted all of the functions and triggers. That script is still trying to run. It still appears in the log file even after everything has been deleted. So there's a different underlying script running, but I have no idea where...

Comment: `insert into machines_spm_storage ( SELECT * FROM machineid3_spm_step4);` I would never expect a `select *  FROM ... WHERE 1=1` in a row-based trigger. Will the target table ever be emptied?

Comment: @wildplasser The table would be emptied out eventually. But this is set up for reporting purposes.

Comment: Nicoale your description doesnt sound logical. My suggestion try to debug each trigger, or create a new database and create the same triggers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I will trying debugging the trigger again. I have completely dropped the database and re-created it. I agree it doesn't logical, but I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: how you recreated? Because if you use a backup then probably you have the problem already there. Try a clean database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to drop the database and start with a clean schema, however when I tried to drop and restore the original (with the data) to see if that would reset whatever was running, I got a `port 5432 already in use` error.

I'm not exactly sure how to explain it - but it's as if there were two occurrences of the database running. After I dropped the database, restarted pgadmin, the database was there but was a previous version. I restored with the latest data (again) and I no longer have a "ghost trigger" running in the background.